# Условные придаточные

Tags: синтаксис

В данный момент работаю над порядком следования частей предложения, выражающих "условие/следствие": если бы + главное предложение / главное предложение + если бы.

Например

Если бы у меня были деньги, я купила бы книгу.

Я купила бы книгу, если бы у меня были деньги.

У Нелисова читаю *Принято считать, что "при постпозиции придаточной части в главной утрачивается значение следствия, а в придаточной развивается ограничительное значение"*.

Кто подскажет, о каком "ограничительном значении" идёт речь? Спасибо!

Answer (score 3):

В первом варианте сложноподчинённого предложения можно трактовать главную его часть "я купила бы книгу" как следствие того, о чём говорится в предшествующей, придаточной части "Если бы у меня были деньги": я бы их потратила - на покупку книги.

В изменённом варианте придаточная часть стоит после главной (этот факт автор и называет её постпозицией), и смысл изменяется. **Ограничительное значение** придаточной части предложения автор видит* в том, что в ней сформулированы условия, при которых возможно то, о чём говорится в главной части, при этом нельзя назвать главную часть "Я купила бы книгу" *следствием* наличия денег. Скорее, есть желание купить (конкретную) книгу, но мешает ("**ограничивает**" эту возможность) отсутствие денег.

*со ссылкой на общепринятую трактовку, возможно, автор это далее оспаривает

Comment: Кстати, вот что пишет Нелисов дальше: 
"На наш взгляд, в структуре сложных условных предложений с союзом "если бы", при наличии частицы "бы" в главной части, значение условно-следственные продолжают сохраняться без всякого "ограничительного" значения придаточной части. Иными словами, употребление нереальных условных придаточных предложений препозитивно или постпозитивно не нарушает грамматической связи "условия - следствия".

Comment: Александр, простите, но что-то я опять запуталась: 
Возьмём простые примеры: 
1) если бы ты купил билет (условие), я бы пошёл в кино (следствие). 
2) я бы пошёл в кино, если бы ты купил билет.
В примере (2) разве нельзя рассматривать "я бы пошёл в кино" как следствие "если бы ты купил билет"?
Разве оно не функционирует по правилу "от перестановки мест...  не меняется"?

Answer (score 3):

Из книги Кустовой "Синтаксис современного русского языка"

При постпозиции придаточного значение предложения **условное**, при препозиции - **условно-следственное**.

Вообще в СПП расчлененного типа (союзная связь) постпозиция придаточного - это основная (нейтральная) позиция, когда выражается основное значение (в данном случае значение условия), главная часть при этом независимая.

В препозиции возникает **взаимообусловленность**  главной и придаточной частей  и происходит модификация грамматического значения предложения. **Придаточная часть может влиять на строение и содержание главной части** (может быть, это называется ограничительным значением).

Comment: ... Вера, Александр, спасибо вам большое за помощь! Вы просто сокровище!!! : )